# Calculating sum of days in LINQ query

Tags: linq

Following is my datatable:

```
ResourceName    ContentName    ProjectName  PlanndStartDate PlannedEndDate   ActualStartDate    ActualEndDate   DesiredDate
ANIL            C-1479.doc     HP_WI_4141   2/24/2014       2/25/2014        2/24/2014          2/24/2014   2/23/2014
ANIL            C-1234.docx    HP_WI_3131   2/1/2014        2/12/2014        2/1/2014           2/13/2014   2/11/2014
CHETNA          C-1479.doc     HP_WI_4141   2/24/2014       2/25/2014        2/24/2014          2/24/2014   2/26/2014
CHETNA          C-1479.doc     HP_WI_4141   2/1/2014        2/12/2014        2/1/2014           2/13/2014   2/10/2014
CHETNA          C-14085.xlsx   HP_WI_5151   2/14/2014       2/28/2014        2/14/2014          2/26/2014   2/26/2014
GAURAV YADAV    C-1479.doc     HP_WI_4141   2/24/2014       2/25/2014        2/24/2014          2/24/2014   2/25/2014
GAURAV YADAV    C-1479.doc     HP_WI_4141   2/1/2014        2/12/2014        2/1/2014           2/13/2014   2/15/2014
GAURAV YADAV    C-14085.xlsx   HP_WI_5151   2/14/2014       2/28/2014        2/14/2014          2/26/2014   2/28/2014
NITIN           C-14077.pdf    HP_WI_2121   2/1/2014        2/12/2014        2/1/2014           2/13/2014   2/13/2014
SRINIVAS        C-14085.xlsx   HP_WI_5151   2/14/2014       2/28/2014        2/14/2014          2/26/2014   2/25/2014
```

Now, By using LINQ query, I have to generate following Result.

```
ResourceName    ContentName ProjectName PlanndStartDate PlannedEndDate  ActualStartDate ActualEndDate   DesiredDate TotalDays   GroupDays
ANIL            C-1479.doc  HP_WI_4141  2/24/2014       2/25/2014       2/24/2014        2/24/2014      2/23/2014        -1      -1
ANIL            C-1234.docx HP_WI_3131  2/1/2014        2/12/2014       2/1/2014         2/13/2014      2/11/2014        -2      -2
CHETNA          C-1479.doc  HP_WI_4141  2/24/2014       2/25/2014       2/24/2014        2/24/2014      2/26/2014         2      -1
CHETNA          C-1479.doc  HP_WI_4141  2/1/2014        2/12/2014       2/1/2014         2/13/2014      2/10/2014        -3      -1
CHETNA          C-14085.xlsxHP_WI_5151  2/14/2014       2/28/2014   2/14/2014                 2/26/2014      2/26/2014    0       0
GAURAV YADAV    C-1479.doc  HP_WI_4141  2/24/2014       2/25/2014       2/24/2014        2/24/2014      2/25/2014         1       3
GAURAV YADAV    C-1479.doc  HP_WI_4141  2/1/2014        2/12/2014       2/1/2014         2/13/2014      2/15/2014         2       3
GAURAV YADAV    C-14085.xlsxHP_WI_5151  2/14/2014       2/28/2014   2/14/2014       2/26/2014        2/28/2014            2       2
NITIN           C-14077.pdf HP_WI_2121  2/1/2014        2/12/2014       2/1/2014         2/13/2014      2/13/2014         0       0
SRINIVAS        C-14085.xlsxHP_WI_5151  2/14/2014       2/28/2014   2/14/2014            2/26/2014       2/25/2014       -1      -1
```

Now, Result should be group by "ResouceName", "ContentName" and "ProjectName" and column "TotalDays" is difference of "DesireEndDate" and "ActualEndDate" and column "GroupDays" is sum of "TodalDays" as per group by.

Please suggest me how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I failed this *find ten differences* puzzle :(

Comment: Could you please tell me, what is wrong in question?

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar show your linq queries

Comment: @Grundy I am new in linq hence I am not able to do it, because of that I have posted it here.

Comment: see msdn about [groupby clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.queryable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupBy` and a loop:

```
var groups = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
             let ResouceName = row.Field<string>("ResouceName")
             let ContentName  = row.Field<string>("ContentName") 
             let ProjectName  = row.Field<string>("ProjectName")
             group row by new{ ResouceName, ContentName, ProjectName } into Group
             select Group;

var tblResult = table.Clone();
tblResult.Columns.Add("TotalDays", typeof(int));
tblResult.Columns.Add("GroupDays", typeof(int);

foreach (var group in groups)
{ 
    int GroupDays = group.Sum(r => (r.Field<DateTime>("DesiredDate") - r.Field<DateTime>("ActualEndDate")).Days);
    foreach(DataRow row in group)
    {
        DateTime PlanndStartDate = row.Field<DateTime>("PlanndStartDate");
        DateTime PlannedEndDate = row.Field<DateTime>("PlannedEndDate");
        DateTime ActualStartDate = row.Field<DateTime>("ActualStartDate"); 
        DateTime ActualEndDate = row.Field<DateTime>("ActualEndDate");
        DateTime DesiredDate = row.Field<DateTime>("DesiredDate");
        TimeSpan Total = DesiredDate - ActualEndDate;
        tblResult.Rows.Add(group.Key.ResouceName, group.Key.ContentName, group.Key.ProjectName, PlanndStartDate, PlannedEndDate, ActualStartDate, ActualEndDate, DesiredDate, Total.Days, GroupDays);
    }
}
```

Comment: why you use `AsEnumerable`? `IQueryably` also have `GroupBy` extension

Comment: @Grundy: because it is an in-memory `DataTable`.

Comment: @Grundy: if it is my answer is not helpful and OP should have been more clear. I thought _"Following is my datatable"_ meant a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: yep, you're right, I read the _"database"_  instead of _"datatable"_

Comment: @Tim: Really thanks for your reply. Its giving me error " Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table". It may be because of two extra columns "Totaldays" and "GroupDays" which is not present in "tblResult".

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar: i thought that your table would already contains these columns. Then you have to add them after `table.Clone();`. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi, How Can get Max "desireDate" from outer foreach loop?